# User Authorization with Roles in ASP.NET 4.x with Okta

Tags: asp.net, okta

I have found a link for User Authorization in ASP.NET Core with Okta

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/04/aspnet-authorization

But we need to implement User Authorization with Roles in ASP.NET 4.8 with Okta. Please do suggest.

Comment: I suggest that you updated your version of .net.